# count(*) gives a wrong result in PostgreSQL for some regex with pg_trm/GIN index

Tags: regex, postgresql

When using some RE to filter rows on gin-indexed column with pg_trm, count(*) could give a wrong result (zero instead of real count):

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE TABLE t (
  s text
);
CREATE INDEX ON t USING gin (s gin_trgm_ops);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('12-34');

SET enable_seqscan = OFF; -- to force using the index on our small table
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE s~'\d{2}[-]?\d{2}'; -- gives me 0
```

But if we will turn on seq scans, we will get the correct result:

```
SET enable_seqscan = ON;
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE s~'\d{2}[-]?\d{2}'; -- gives me 1
```

I believe this is a bug, but to report it, I should try all this on the latest PostgreSQL version (mine is 9.5.4) but for some reasons I cannot do this. So, can anybody with a latest PG confirm this wrong behavior?

PS or maybe it's not a bug and there is something wrong with my brain/hands))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks a lot! Now need someone with 9.5.5 =)

Comment: Works for me with 9.5.3, 9.5.4, 9.5.5 and 9.6.1

Comment: it's pretty strange. because I run it on my local PG and on Amazon RDS (also 9.5.4) and everywhere I get zero as a result.

Here are the versions I've tried:
PostgreSQL 9.5.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
Are you really sure that it works for you on all mentioned versions?
Because all other people who I have asked to test this, had same behavior as mine.
So in the end I was able to install 9.6.1, got same bug and reported it.
As I understood Tom Lane confirmed that it's a bug:
https://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg305861.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that it was really a bug.
Don't know the final status, but as I understand, the fix has been committed:
https://github.com/michaelpq/postgres/commit/9e43e8714c9e976e41b7429fa7c426c9a6e5e8e6